# MVVM implementation with RxSwift and Realm - Two way binding

Tags: swift, mvvm, data-binding, realm, rx-swift

My implementation of the MVVM pattern with RxSwift, Realm and RxRealm looks like this:

[image: MVVM pattern with realm and RxSwift]

E.g. I have a textfield that shows some editable content. I want this to be realtime saved/synched to the DB like this:

```
//View
textField.rx.text.subscribe(textViewModel.saveText.inputs)
viewModel.stringValue.drive(textField.rx.text)

//ViewModel:
lazy var saveText = Action<String,Void>{ newStringValue in 
   realm.write{
     textObject.stringValue = newStringValue
   }
  //don't block the main thread
  return Observable.just()
}  

lazy var stringValue = Observable(from:textObject).map{$0.stringValue}.asDriver(onErrorJustReturn : "no string")
```

When typing slowly in the TextField, everything works accordingly. When typing very quickly thought, letters get "swallowed" like this:

1. Type "A"
2. write "A" to DB
3. Type "B"
4. Receive "A" from DB 
   -> Textfield value becomes A instead of AB.

When working with realtime synchronization this is the desired behaviour. For single text typing this seems not a good solution. How would such a 2-way binding be properly implemented and the undesired effect be avoided, especially in a scenario where the viewModel is processing the text value before  write or after read from the source?

Answer (score 1):

In your requirements will the Realm stored data ever be updated via another source? As in, could you ever receive a value in the string that came from another field?

If not, then you may be able to trust your input, and your writes can be eventually consistent.

The problem, though, comes down to the speed of writes and the notification returning the data; small but not nothing. Perhaps an intermediary would be beneficial.

For example, write your input field out to value that will periodically synchronise to Realm. That way your observable can have immediate access to the updated value and you can trust that eventually the value will be

Happy to explore further to see if we can solve something. :)

**Edit:**

Realm's guidance on [conflict resolution](https://realm.io/docs/realm-object-server/latest/#conflict-resolution).

A manual approach might be to hold two values; one is the value you start with, the other is the value that is being managed by the server.

If the starting value and the server value differ, you have a conflict to manage. Your strategy can be to reject one, accept one or somehow merge them, depending on the complexity of the data.

Comment: The data can also be coming from other users via the realm object server - also from other sources but not concurrently (except the ROS). i also thought about an intermediate but that’s an additional layer - is there a good design pattern for it fitting in MVVM? Would it be in the Viewmodel or would I have to wrap my Realm models into Object controllers or something like that.

Comment: @hakkurishian https://realm.io/docs/realm-object-server/latest/#conflict-resolution has some guidance on conflict resolution.

Comment: I get the point of conflict resolution - but my question relates to the Dataflow/Architecture of such a client-side intermediate-layer between what is currently my Model and ViewModel which takes into account the values coming from realm and the values coming from the text field.When subscribing to the model and throttling the writes I would have of know whether the change is coming from the client or from the server Would it be wise to store the "last editor" in the db on every write and only subscribe to values coming not from the "me" author while editing?

Comment: Have you figured out any approach on this, I am also having same issue. If yes please let me know, I am thinking the best way to do this update non-realm model whenever UI gets updated and save data in realm DB in the background.  like old way approach. about server update need to validate non realm model and realm model on the server update.